# Limiting the user input to a fixed length

Tags: python, python-3.5

I want to limit the user input to a fixed length, and then I have to multiply it. I want the `C` value as an integer. How do I get this?

```
def F_to_C():
    F=int(input("enter the F value:"))  
    if len(F) >3:
        print("input is too long")
    else:
        C=(F-32)*(5/9)
        print("the corresponding celcius value is: ",C)
```

My Error:

```
if len(F)>3:
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a bit more of context/explanation. Also it looks like your code is for python3, if this is the case please remove the python2 tag.

Comment: Check the length **before** you cast to ``int``? Or check if the int is > 999 (but that would mean that -10000 is valid). You could also check with ``F in range(..., ...)`` if you know the valid boundaries.

Comment: Why do you _want_ to limit the length? Valid temperatures can have more than 3 digits.

Comment: Your full question goes into the huge empty box. The smaller box "Title" is for a short description *only*.

Comment: Your `F` is an integer when you check for the length (`if len(F) > 3`). You should check this before casting to int.

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant under `1000`:

```
def F_to_C():
  F=int(input("enter the F value:"))  
  if F>999:
      print("input is too long")
  else:
      C=(F-32)*(5/9)
      print("the corresponding celcius value is: ",C)
```

Then:

```
F_to_C()
```

Example Output:

```
enter the F value:234
the corresponding celcius value is:  112.22222222222223
```

If want as integer (rounding):

```
def F_to_C():
  F=int(input("enter the F value:"))  
  if F>999:
      print("input is too long")
  else:
      C=round((F-32)*(5/9))
      print("the corresponding celcius value is: ",C)
```

If just want to round down to become just the number part:

```
def F_to_C():
  F=int(input("enter the F value:"))  
  if F>999:
      print("input is too long")
  else:
      C=int((F-32)*(5/9))
      print("the corresponding celcius value is: ",C)
```

Answer (score 1):

So, the error message is clear enough I think: the variable `F` is a integer and it has no `len()`. Try this:

```
def F_to_C():
    F = input("enter the F value:")  
    if len(F) > 3:
        print("input is too long")
    else:
        C=(int(F)-32)*(5/9)
        print("the corresponding celcius value is: ",C)
```

or the code from @U9-Forward

Comment: Oh @U9-Forward, I'm sorry, I'll soon have my answer editted.

Answer (score 1):

```
F=int(input("enter the F value:"))
```

reads a string and transforms it into an int

```
if len(F) >3:
```

Here you are trying to read the length of an int, which is not possible

Try this:

```
def F_to_C():
F=input("enter the F value:")
if len(F) >3:
    print("input is too long")
else:
    C=(int(F)-32)*(5/9)
    print("the corresponding celcius value is: ",C)
```

First it will check the length of the string F, then when it calculates C it transforms F into an int.